# React native crypto stream module is undefined

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules, node-streams

I'm giving a try with `[react-native-crypto][1]` in order to learn how to convert nodejs to be used in React Native project in the future. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it running successfully. I've faced an issue with `stream` is undefined.  `ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "stream").Transform.call')`.

If you have ever faced a similar problem, I'm so grateful for your help.

Also, I attach the screenshot of the issue as the following [image]

Comment: hi @sinal, were you able to solve this issue. I tried same thing you answered but didn't got any luck. could you please help me in this. thankyou

Comment: @AmitRana did you follow my answer below? I did the same thing in answer below and it worked for me. Could you confirm you edited your metro.config.js ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still trying to solve this issue, I have figured out a solution that worked for me. So within `node_modules/cipher-base/index.js`, the top of the file should have a line which defines the variable Transform as `var Transform = require('stream').Transform`. For some reason, it does not like the module `stream` and as such it needs to be changed to `readable-stream`. Therefore the variable Transform should now read `var Transform = require('readable-stream').Transform`.

From what I have gathered, the `stream` module it is trying to refer to isnt actually a module that can be used. The reason why it gets referenced however seems to be because the `tsconfig.json` file in the root directory specifies `"stream": ["./node_modules/readable-stream"]` as a path, almost as if to make `stream` refer to the `readable-stream` module, which in theory it should refer to when it is called. But in this case it doesnt happen so we need to explicitly define that we are refering to the `readable-stream` module.

Hope this helps anyone else out there and prevents others scratching their heads for hours on end like it did for me!

Answer (score -1):

I have figured it out by editing in `metro.config.js` as the following:

```
resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: {
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    }
  },
```

Comment: I followed your answer, however I still get the error. Are you sure this solved yours? 
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it surely worked for me.